# What is $Bd(Bd([0,1]))$?

Tags: real-analysis

I had a discussion with a friend about the boundary of the boundary, and we do not agree, that's why I ask you the question. For exemple, if $A=[0,1]$, what is $Bd(Bd(A))$ ? To me it's $\{0,1\}$ since $\{0,1\}$ $$Bd(\{0,1\})=Cl(\{0,1\})\backslash Int(\{0,1\})=\{0,1\},$$
but my friend think that it's $\emptyset$. So, who is correct, and why ?

Comment: You are both right, for different senses of the word boundary. The *topological* boundary of the topological boundary of $[0, 1]$ (regarded as a subset of $\Bbb R$, for example) is the topological boundary of $\{0, 1\}$, which is again just $\{0, 1\}$. On the other hand, if we regard $[0, 1]$ as a manifold with boundary, its (manifold) boundary is $\partial[0, 1] = \{0, 1\}$, and the (manifold) boundary of $\{0, 1\}$ is (as for any $0$-manifold) the empty set. More generally, for any manifold-with-boundary $M$ it's true that $\partial \partial M = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The closure of $\{0,1\}$ is itself, the interior is empty.

However, note that the boundary of $A$ is $\{0,1\}$ when it's considered as a subset of the real line. However, if you consider $A$ as a topological space on its own, then its boundary is empty. This may be the misunderstanding between you and your friend.

Comment: But take for exemple the sphere. It's boundary is $\emptyset$, where as it should be the sphere. It's a little bit confusiong...

Comment: @MSE The boundary of the whole space is always empty, because no point can be in the closure of the complement (which is empty). So if you consider $[0,1]$ as *the* space, then the boundary is empty. If $[0,1]$ is a subset of the real line, then its boundary is $\{0,1\}$.